# Checking RAM Bays (Windows API)

Tags: winapi, memory, hardware

I know that it is possible to check how much physical RAM is installed using `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` or how much ram the operating system can see using `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`.  However, I am wondering if there is any way to check how much ram a user has installed by slot.  That is, to be able to programmatically tell the difference between 1x2GB of ram and 2x1GB of ram, thus checking if the computer can be upgraded easily via software.  Ideally, a way to check this without .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WMI to look at Win32_PhysicalMemory. Look at the Capacity and Bank Label properties.

UPDATED: You do not need .NET for this. See [Creating a WMI Application Using C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(VS.85).aspx) for examples in C++

Comment: The above properties and others look to be exactly the things CPU-Z [http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php] would use. CPU-Z can do exactly the sort of things you're after.

Comment: I suspected WMI could do this, but I am pretty sure WMI requires .net.

Comment: The WMI Scriptomatic [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178&displaylang=en] is a good starting point for reading WMI properties before you sit down and write any code.

Comment: WMI does not require .NET (although it's easier with it)

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the MSDN docs for the functions listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300158(VS.85).aspx), I see that the function checks with the SMBIOS table, which is referenced by a standard [here](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/published_documents/DSP0134_2.6.0.pdf)
It appears that you indeed can find the information you seek through the BIOS. You may have to install a driver to get that information out to your program.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need WMI (always avoid WMI (slow)), neither any driver (of course)
Use standard Win32 SMB apis

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I can almost always find that information with dmidecode, which parses the DMI tables from the BIOS. It shows all the memory slots and what is on each one, together with other interesting information. I don't know how to get the DMI data on Windows, however.